# Clarify proof of theorem 6.6 Fredholm alternative in Haim Brezis book (Funtional Analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I'm currently reading proof of this theorem.
[image]

My question is in part b), it says that:
[image]

I have already wrote
[image]

But i'm not sure why $w_{n_k}-Tw_{n_k}$ corverges to $0$, which is implies from $(4)$. Can you clarify this? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @jd27: $w_{n_k}$ is defined in the proof included in the question, concretely in the few sentences after $(4)$. And OP's question is very clearly stated at the end of his post.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you are right, i missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $(4)$ gives you the expression you wrote,
$$
w_{n_k}-Tw_{n_k}=\frac{f_{n_k}}{\|u_{n_k}-v_{n_k}\|}.
$$
The fact that $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converges
guarantees that it is bounded. And the hypothesis is that the denominator goes to infinity, so the whole thing goes to zero.

Comment: Oh I understood, thank you a lot